# Interview questions

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity

This is an interview question:

```
Given: f(n) = O(n)
       g(n) = O(n²)
find f(n) + g(n) and f(n)⋅g(n)?
```

What would be the answer for this question?

Comment: What is the `0` in `0(n^2)`? Big theta?

Comment: they mentioned it as order of n^2. so i believe it is big theta.

Comment: But you've now edited to a big-Oh? They are not synonymous.

Comment: What does the dot represent in `f(n).g(n)`? Function composition?

Comment: I rolled back the edit. It is big theta

Comment: sorry. It is big one only. f(n).g(n) -> it is just basic multiplication.

Comment: @sbala_20 Is it only Big Oh? Why did you have theta before?

Comment: @jamylak and OP: All those edits alternating between `O(n)` and `o(n)` for `f(n)` make for one really confusing question. We need one definitive edit stating clearly whether it's big-Oh or little-oh.

Comment: Hey..sorry. that was typo. Instead of typing 'o' in keyboard i pressed '0' (zero) and that had became confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When this answer was prepared, f(n) was shown as o(n) and g(n) as Θ(n²).

From f(n) = o(n) and g(n) = Θ(n²) you get a lower bound of  o(n²) for f(n) + g(n), but you don't get an upper bound on  f(n) + g(n) because no upper bound was given on f(n). [Note, in above, Θ is a big-θ, or big theta]

For f(n)·g(n), you get a lower bound of o(n³) because Θ(n²) implies lower and upper bounds of  o(n²) and O(n²) for g(n).  Again, no upper bound on  f(n)·g(n) is available, because f(n) can be arbitrarily large;  for f(n), we only have an o(n) lower bound.

With the question modified to give only upper bounds on f and g, as f(n) = O(n) and g(n) = O(n²), we have that f(n)+g(n) is O(n²) and f(n)·g(n) is O(n³).

To show this rigorously is a bit tedious, but is quite 
straightforward.  Eg, for the f(n)·g(n) case, suppose that by the definitions of O(n) and O(n²) we are given C, X, K, Y such that n>X ⇒ C·n > f(n) and n>Y ⇒ K·n² > g(n).  Let J=C·K and Z=max(X,Y).  Then n>Z ⇒ J·n³ > f(n)·g(n) which proves that f(n)·g(n) is O(n³).

Answer (score 1):

```
O(f(n) + g(n)) = O(max{f(n), g(n)})
```

so for first

```
f(n) + g(n) = O(max{n, n^2}) = O(n^2)
```

for

```
f(n) ⋅ g(n)
```

we  will have

```
O(f(n) ⋅ g(n)) = O(n ⋅ n^2) = O(n^3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about it this way.

f(n) = c.n + d 
g(n) = a.n^2 + b.n + p

Then, 
f(n) + g(n) = a.n^2 + (lower powers of n)
And, 
f(n).g(n) = x.n^3 + (lower powers of n)

It follows that O(f(n) + g(n)) = O(n^2)

and O(f(n).g(n)) = O(n^3)

Answer (score 0):

This question can be understood like this :-

> f(n)=O(n) means it takes O(n) time to compute f(n).

Similarly,

> for g(n) which requires O(n^2) time

So,

> P(n)=f(n)+g(n) would definitely take O(n)+O(n^2)+O(1)(for addition,
>   once you know the value of both f and g)

. Hence, this new function

**P(n) would require O(n^2) time**.

Same is the case for

> Q(n) =f(n)*g(n) which requires O(n^2) time

.